# Setup ping reply

Tags: networking, firewall, ping, aws

I have Ubuntu machine running on AWS cloud. System not replies to ping from Interet side. How to enable this?

I have Enabled UDP port 7 in inbound rule, but this not helped.

Content of     /etc/ufw/before.rules

```
# quickly process packets for which we already have a connection
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# drop INVALID packets (logs these in loglevel medium and higher)
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

# ok icmp codes for INPUT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# ok icmp code for FORWARD
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# allow dhcp client to work
-A ufw-before-input -p udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT

#
# ufw-not-local
#
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local

# if LOCAL, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN

# if MULTICAST, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN

# if BROADCAST, RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN

# all other non-local packets are dropped
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP

# allow MULTICAST mDNS for service discovery (be sure the MULTICAST line above
# is uncommented)
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 224.0.0.251 --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT

# allow MULTICAST UPnP for service discovery (be sure the MULTICAST line above
# is uncommented)
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -d 239.255.255.250 --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT
```

OS:
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

Comment: What OS/release please; I note you have tagged 14.04.

Comment: It is Ubuntu 18.04.3

Answer (score 0):

ICMP is disabled by default on AWS services. Did you enable it?

For ping to work:

- Every hop between you and the instance has to allow icmp packets.
- The EC2 firewall for the instance has to be opened to icmp packets using the `ec2-authorize` command (-> EC2 instance -> security group -> inbound rule "allow 0.0.0.0/0" for `ICMP`)
- The instance has to be configured to respond to ping requests.

Only the last 1 is related to Ubuntu.

I would recommend using `ssh` to test connectivity. Use `ec2-authorize` to grant access to port `tcp/22` and try connecting to your instance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a rule that denies this by default. Try to delete it, see if this works.

```
sudo iptables -D INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j REJECT
```